# custom test function - JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create a function like below.
This is the expect function of jest. I want to create this function in Javascript. 
Is this do-able??

```
let type = 'apple'
expect(type).toBe('apple')  

//pass a string to "expect" function and it checks with 'toBe' function if the string is similar
```

**Update**: I know we can do something like below but i am unable to do something like this **"expect().toBe()"**

```
  var Expect = Expect || {};

  Expect.String = function() {
  var toBe = "tobe";

    var toBe = function() {
      console.log("toBE function");
    };

    return {
      toBe: toBe
    }
  }()

Expect.String.toBe(); // this will log "toBe function"
```

Comment: Yes, this is doable. What have you tried so far? What's the desired output of this function?

Comment: Jest is written in JavaScript, so yes it's certainly doable.

Comment: @Nick please check the update. how can i add a module to a function
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a small example of what you are likely going for. You want `expect` to be a function that returns an object where one of the keys, `toBe`, is a function. In this example, I just have it returning `true` or `false` depending on whether the actual equals expected value.

```js
function expect(actual) {
  return {
    toBe: function(expected) {
      return actual === expected;
    }
  }
}

console.log(
  expect("foo").toBe("foo")
);

console.log(
  expect("foo").toBe("bar")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to not reinvent the wheel, but since you are already there, here is what I recommend in a nutshell:

- The function `expect()` takes a `first thing`(a.k.a actual) and returns an object that contains yet another function: `toBe()`
- The function `toBe()` takes `second thing` (a.k.a expected) as a parameter, uses some form of comparator against the `first thing`, and returns a boolean
- For simplicity, the comparator can be `==`

Based on these three elements, Your re-invented `expect()` function can take the alike of the following shape:

```js
function expect(actual){ 
  return { 
    toBe: function(expected){
      return actual == expected;
    }
  }
}
```

- The actual implementation is a little more complicated than this answer ~ For the real-world implementation of [`expect` in Jest is at this GitHub address](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/64d5983d20a628d68644a3a4cd0f510dc304805a/packages/expect/src/index.ts#L86)
- The "matchers" (as they call alikes of `toBe()`, `toEqual()`, etc) can [also be found in this source code](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/64d5983d20a628d68644a3a4cd0f510dc304805a/packages/expect/src/matchers.ts#L74)